# My Always On Display doesn't deactivate at the set time

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s7

I have turned on Always On Display for daytime only, but the screen stays on after the end time (midnight) just displaying the clock, as it does during the day. If I manually lock the phone (Samsung Galaxy S7) after the end time it works as expected (the screen turns off) and Always On Display turns back on by itself at the right time. Is this fixable?

I have tested this with an end time after the start time and before midnight and it works properly. I haven't yet tried setting the end time to after midnight and before the start time to see what that does. So far I can only confirm that the issue happens with an end time set to midnight.

#### EDIT

I have tested various settings and this issue only happens when the end time is exactly midnight. It seems that it gets confused about which date midnight is on and does nothing. The workaround is to set the end time to 11:59 pm or 12:01 am. It looks like a simple bug and not user-controllable.

Comment: Do Not Disturb disables all notification and calls from ringing. Try calling your phone from a different one when DND is turned on automatically (add a temporary rule in case you can't do that during the set time) and check if the audio sounds. As for Always on display, that might be on because it was on previously. Without comment from Samsung we cannot confirm if this is either a bug or intended behaviour.

Comment: @Roh_mish Sorry, it turns out it wasn't Do Not Disturb, but Always On Display exhibiting this behaviour. I had the times for both complementing each other.